# What does the =$1 mean in url rewriting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't find any information on stackoverflow or google about the meaning of `=$1`. I get superficial information but nothing for beginners like me. What does it do?

If I have something like this:

```
www.website.com/profile.php?simon
```

Does the name simon correspond to the `$1` variable and **why 1**?

This is how I understand it:

- `(.*) profile/profile.php?`**id=$1**

The bold corresponds to:

- `www.website.com/profile.php?`**id=simon**

Converted with rewrite it becomes:

- `www.website.com/profile/simon`

Am I missing something here?

Edit:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile/index.php?id=$1
```

Does this change

localhost/test/index.php?philip
to:
localhost/test/profile/philip

I tried to enter the url but it failed. I understand what regex does but somehow im utterly confusing how the replacement works.

Comment: It's a back-reference, what was captured  in the first group `()` in the pattern.  If there was another group it would be `$2`, etc.

Comment: @AbraCadaver (.*) means whatever matches the request has to be replaced with what comes after it. In my example does the profile.php get replaced with id=$1. What exactly do you mean with backreference? I mean in how far

Comment: @Asperger see my example in my answer for a URL like `http://www.example.com/profile/philip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain in layman's terms.

Let's say you would normally link to a page like this...

/listing.php?id=2146_east_fifth_street

Then you create a rewrite rule like this...

`RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$    listing.php?id=$1    [NC,L]`

This part `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$` says to accept any querystring parameter with uppercase letters / lowercase letters / 0-9 / underscores / hyphens

This part `listing.php?id=$1` says what page will be served up to the browser. the `$1` asks for the first querystring parameter and appends it to the URL like this... your-domain.com/2146_east_fifth_street

That's what you see in the URL bar instead of... your-domain.com/listing.php?id=2146_east_fifth_street

**EDIT**

The second part of the rewrite rule is where the "real" page is located.

If you want your url to read /profile/philip

Your rewrite rule would start with /profile/ like this...

`RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ path/to/the/real/file/index.php?id=$1`

Comment: Check my edited question. I think I understood, if I did not, let me know please.

Comment: i my XAMMP htdocs the folder of my site is "test". Do I include this in my url inside the real url?

Comment: No... all files for the site should be in that folder. Correct?

Comment: So the first part is the regex that checks for a match. In this case we explicitly set it to profile and anything after that (alex, philip, 332, etc) is allowed. The second part is the url that is replaced and id=1 is a placeholder that comes everything that matched against our regex

Comment: All my files, including the htaccess, are in my test folder. The folder named test is inside the htdocs of XAMMP. So I get localhost/test/somepage

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ localhost/test/your-page-name.php?id=$1`

Not that familiar with xamp... sorry. I use a testing server in the web

Comment: It is ok. The principle should be the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88736/discussion-between-kuya-and-asperger).

Answer (score 6):

Backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /?id=$1
```

**$1** would be blank

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?id=$1
```

**$1** would be whatever `.*` matched

```
RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/(d|e|f)$ /?id=$1-$2
```

**$1** would be either "a", "b", or "c", depending on which one matched, and **$2** would be either "d", "e", or "f", depending on which one matched.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html#regex

> One important thing here has to be remembered: Whenever you use parentheses in *Pattern* or in one of the *CondPattern*, back-references are internally created which can be used with the strings `$N` and `%N` (see below). These are available for creating the *Substitution* parameter of a `RewriteRule` or the *TestString* parameter of a `RewriteCond`.
>
> Captures in the `RewriteRule` patterns are (counterintuitively) available to all preceding `RewriteCond` directives, because the `RewriteRule` expression is evaluated before the individual conditions.
>
> Figure 1 shows to which locations the back-references are transferred for expansion as well as illustrating the flow of the `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond` matching. In the next chapters, we will be exploring how to use these back-references, so do not fret if it seems a bit alien to you at first.
>
> [image]

---

> Does this change
>
> `localhost/test/index.php?philip` to: `localhost/test/profile/philip`

No, It changes `localhost/test/profile/philip` to `localhost/profile/index.php?id=philip`. Assuming that the rule is in an htaccess file that is in your "profile" directory, then:

1. Browser types in or clicks on the link: `localhost/test/profile/philip`
2. The request is sent to localhost: `/test/profile/philip`
3. The request makes its way through apache's processing pipeline and mod_rewrite is applied to it, and the request is truncated to `philip`
4. Assuming that `philip` is neither a directory or file, the rule matches `(.*)` to it, and the string `philip` is captured
5. The rule then **rewrites** the request to `/profile/index.php?id=philip`

Comment: Great explanation but I am still a little bit stuck. I edited my question and added more code. Let me know if I understood this

Comment: I added /test/ to the rewrite and then entered the url localhost/test/profile/index.php?id=philip   but I get a not found

Comment: @Asperger why are you going to `localhost/test/profile/index.php?id=philip`? The concept is simple. a rewrite rule: `RewriteRule <THIS> <THAT>` changes `THIS` to `THAT`. The URL that you tried is the `<THAT>`. This isn't even in the scope of the question you originally asked.

Comment: You are right. You did answer my question. I will upvote in a minute. I will try and reflect on what I learned here

Answer (score 3):

First, use Apache documentation rather than Google searches or Forums it's more helpful.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regex

And this

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Now `(.*)` is a parenthesized capture group in Regex. It says to match any single character and the asterisk means to repeat it `0` or more times.

When there is only 1 capture group. The numbered back reference is `$1`. Additional capture groups used or added will then be `$2`, `$3` and so on.

For this example

```
www.website.com/profile/simon
```

You would get this rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule (.*) profile/profile.php?id=$1
```

But your back reference `$1` won't be `simon`, it will be `profile/simon` because you matched all characters requested using `(.*)`.

If you only want to match `simon` you need to use a partial match like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/?$ profile/profile.php?id=$1
```

Then your `$1` will only be `simon` and also the rule won't match any empty strings, meaning if there is no text after /profile/ it won't process the rewrite.

Comment: I understand how the regex works since I learned some basics in php but htaccess is really new to me. I will try this out right now and let you know

Comment: http://localhost/test/profile/simon   : requested url not found when tested on XAMMP

Comment: rewrite is RewriteRule (.*) profile/profile.php?id=$1

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located and did you try my actual example?

Comment: htaccess is in the test folder. Im trying to create a virtual profile folder though. The folder profile does not exist. I enter names manually in the browser for testing.

Comment: I have this in place that enables folder rewrite RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -d

Comment: If profile doesn't exist then what is `profile/profile.php` about?

Comment: I can create a virtual folder. Currently testing this RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ test/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]   with some help

Comment: if `test` is defined as your document root then it shouldn't be included in your rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

in .htaccess `$1` is a back-reference to a group, usually from a regex statement. 
Each group has its own reference, so a rewrite like

```
RewriteRule /profile/(.*)/([0-9]) /profile/index.php/$1/$2
```

`$1` would equal the value of `(.*)` that group

`$2` would equal the value of `([0-9])` which can only include numbers

and so on...

It helps when id numbers and url's are dynamic. So you do not need to manually add them one by one.

Example url:

```
 website.com/profile/idealcastle/25555
```

And then in php or other languages, you can pull these "url segments". Just like using a "query" parameter, `?id=simon` It's much better to use proper urls for SEO purposes.