# How to rewrite url remove slug /product/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a sample link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/test/index.php/product/01-00030am-1a1y
```

I want remove /product it become to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/test/index.php/01-00030am-1a1y
```

This is .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^test/index.php/product/(.*)$ test/index.php/$2 [R=301]
```

But it never work, how to fix it

Comment: Yes @anubhava - error page not found. I using wordpress cms

Comment: If you're getting 404 for `/test/index.php/01-00030am-1a1y` then it will have to done through WP rewrite API not in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I believe its `$1` not `$2`

`$2` would refer to the second matched group which you haven't set it. Try:

```cs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^test/index.php/product/(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. [Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Check [here](https://linchpinseo.com/htaccess-rules/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382466/what-does-the-1-mean-in-url-rewriting) for more info about .htaccess rules.

Also please make sure that you have [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) `on` otherwise, it will not work. If not, I guess you can add it in your .htaccess

```cs
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^test/index.php/product/(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As an alternative, If you're using WooCommerce, give [woo-permalink-manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/) plugin a try.